# Is there a good comprehensive walk-through of deriving the math for 3D model rendering that starts from scratch?

Tags: 3d

I'd like to fully understand the math of rendering a 3D model in a 2D perspective.

I always find tutorials that are in terms of the APIs used to do the math for you, and not the math itself.

I'd like to understand it from the standpoint of geometry as opposed to linear algebra if possible.  What I mean is, I'd like to be able to visualize what the matricies stand for in the 3D model and/or 2D image which is the result of rendering.

Is there a definitive source or sources I can consult for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some old books like : 
-3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development (namely [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556229119))

You can get yourself an ebook. Just make a little search. Of course I would suggest the legal way :) .

Next you can search for software rendering. The topics you would like to read about are :

- Matrices (rotation, translation, projection, multiplying)
- Rasterization (that's a topic not many people dare to venture into
- bilinear filtering, trilinear filtering (and others)
- Quaternions
- Z buffer , visibility checking
- Occlusion querries

By the time you learn all about it, you will know what to learn next .